# Truly cross-browser way to get document height?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web

I have a control contained in an iframe on a page of my ASP.NET web application.
Control changes its vertical size correspondingly to what user selects on it (some elements get in, others get out). So, I have to set the iframe size precisely to get the whole control shown and not to make gap between the iframe and the elements below it.

Somewhere on the web I have found a way to get the document height in a cross-browser way:

```
        function getDocHeight(document) {
        return Math.max(
            Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight),
            Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
            Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        );
    }
```

On self.document.body.onload on the control page, hence, I call this function:

```
        function adjustIframeHeight() {
        var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById(window.frameElement.id);
        var iframeHeight = getDocHeight(iframe.contentWindow.document);
        iframe.style.height = iframeHeight + "px";
    }
```

The problem is it works fine e.g. in Firefox, but in some cases bottom sections of the control are cutoff in Chrome and IE for example.

Is there some truly cross-browser way to get this height, or I am doing something else wrong?
Thank you for the time

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like jQuery to help out with this (since using height methods seem to vary from browser to browser) and here is some jQuery code that could help out:

```
$(document).height(); // height of HTML doc
```

Comment: Actually it gives me the same results with jQuery. I am starting to figure out what is the problem : only if images are at the bottom I do get them cutoff. I looks the frame height is calculated before the images load.  when I do page refresh the frame gets the proper height. Do you have some idea how to tell images to load before. I am using ASP.NET ImageButton-s and I am setting their ImageUrl property